# When is this map a permutation of $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following map
$$f:\mathbb{Z}^{n}\to \mathbb{Z}^{n}: t\mapsto q-q'+z-z'+ C^{-1}t$$
where $q,q'\in\mathbb{Q}^{n}$; $z,z'\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}$; and $C\in\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$. This map is required to be a permutation of $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$. This is the case when $q=q'$ and $C\in\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ but are there other situations in which $f$ is a permutation?

Comment: When $t = 0$ you have $f(t) = q-q'+z-z'$ so that $q-q'$ has to be integer, so equivalently you can consider whether $C^{-1}t$ is a permutation of $\Bbb Z^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any ***bijective function*** $\;f\;$ will permute $\;\mathbb{Z}^n.\quad$ Why?

Note that $f(0) = q - q' + z - z' \implies q - q' \in \mathbb{Z}$;

Now determine when $\;C^{−1}t\;$ is a permutation of $\;\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: And that is the case when $C\in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, right?